# Torch not running from cronjob

Tags: python, cron, torch

I have a torch code that creates an output image from an input image code here

```
result = os.system("th colorize.lua {0} {1}".format('/root/images/'+image, '/root/images/'+new_name))
```

if I run it manually with `python color.py`, this runs the script above, it works fine but it fails as a cronjob. I've added a script to log `result` incase of failure and it returns `32512`. It should return 0 when running okay. According to what I've found this means I need to run the "entire script" correctly.

From the crontab I've activated it using

```
*/1 * * * * python /root/images/color.py
```

Comment: it is possible your cron does not use the same python version. Instead of writing python in the cron file write the result of `which python` (something like /usr/bin/local/python)

Comment: In general, it's likely `cron` is running with a different `PATH` than you are. You'll probably want to declare the absolute path of `th` too.